# What is the best way to generate a snapshot given latitude and longitude, skipping MKMapView is really encouraged

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, snapshot

I am implementing location sharing in my APP, this forces me to generate multiple snapshots according to their latitude and longitude accordingly. So simply using directly:

```
- (UIImage*) renderToImage:(MKMapView*) view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

will lead me a un-finished snapshot.

I tried to use following code:

```
 - (void)mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView fullyRendered:(BOOL)fullyRendered
    {
        // Image creation code here   
    }
```

However, it's hard for me to get back to the right cell setting a snapshot even I know it is fully loaded.

So is there some API to generate the snapshot directly from the latitude and longitude without these complex procedure? Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MKMapSnapshotter` for this purpose. It allows you to create an image of a map at a specific location, centered on a region.

```
- (void)renderSnapshotForLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location {
    MKMapSnapshotOptions *options = [[MKMapSnapshotOptions alloc] init];
    options.size = CGSizeMake(200, 200); // whatever size you need
    options.scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    // size of region in degrees of latitude and longitude
    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.25, 0.25);
    options.region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span);

    MKMapSnapshotter *snapshotter = [[MKMapSnapshotter alloc] initWithOptions:options];
    [snapshotter startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKMapSnapshot * _Nullable snapshot, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if(snapshot){
            UIImage *mapImage = snapshot.image;
            // do what you need with the image
            return;
        }

        NSLog(@"Error rendering snapshot for map at: (%f, %f)", options.region.center.latitude, options.region.center.longitude);
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];
}
```

There is a pretty [good article on NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/mktileoverlay-mkmapsnapshotter-mkdirections/) about `MKMapSnapshotter`.

Comment: It's good to know MKMapSnapshotter, but I am still a little bit confused. with a [snapshotter startWithCompletionHandler:^()] block in another function renderSnapshotForLocation: (CLLocationCoordinate2D)location, how am I able set image for the specific cell in the UITableview at the right time?

Comment: That depends - when is "the right time"? The snapshot is pretty fast, I use it to lazy load images when they are needed and the delay isn't that noticeable. You could change the signature to `renderSnapshotForlocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location inCell:(UITableViewCell*) cell` and set the image for `cell` in the callback. It sounds like you want something that is completely synchronous, but I doubt you really want to block the UI until the map images are rendered. Start the snapshot as soon as possible, and put the image where it's needed when it is done.

Comment: Thanks, renderSnapshotForlocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location inCell:(UITableViewCell*) cell is what I need :)

Comment: @CodeFarmer Great! Glad I could help. Happy coding.